Why do we Brief Jeppesen Charts from right to left?
During my IFR training, we used jeppesen charts. I've been informed by my flight instructors that we start briefing a Jeppesen chart from top right to top left. For example, we start reading the city name and procedure, then the index number and revision date, and then the icao/easa code and airport name. However, I'm having trouble understanding why it's like this. I asked my instructors and none could give me a convincing answer. Why is it not top left to top right? Is there a document that specifies this? I couldn't find it.

What you need to do is to have somebody show you a Jeppesen binder, from the days before iPads.
Imagine you have a book or binder and you're trying to find the right page. When quickly fanning through the pages, the most visible portion is the part furthest away from the binding. This means the top right on right-hand pages. That's where they print the city name and procedure, which you're searching for. Your briefing flow starts there, so it has to go left.
You'll find this universal: Jeppesen, FAA, Lido, NavBlue, UK AIP, etc.
One could start from the top left on left-hand pages, but due to Western left-hand binding, the top right is natural.
You could also use the bottom right, and in fact FAA charts repeat the information there.

This is for the same reason page numbers (and more generally "folios" including page number, running header, important information, etc) are aligned with the outer margin, and sections start on a odd page.
